# How do I disable syntax highlighting within a heredoc in shell scripts?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

There are several questions here on how to use different syntax highlighting within heredocs, but I want to just disable it. I can expand upon any answers I get here for other syntaxes within other filetypes.

I want to disable syntax highlighting in heredocs with these matches at the start:

```
cat << EOF
cat <<-EOF
```

I have come up with this, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
# after/syntax/sh.vim
syntax region hereDocText matchgroup=Statement start=+<<[-\s]*EOF end=+^EOF contains=NONE
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by disable, and why?  the region needs to be highlighted as _something_ and it isn't sh script.  what would it look like upon disabling?

Comment: @Mass As in no syntax highlighting within the heredoc. I am usually using plain English within the heredocs and it's especially annoying when there is an apostrophe that screws up the syntax highlighting on the rest of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have malformed syntax command, following one should work:

```
syntax region hereDocText matchgroup=Statement start=+<<[-[:space:]]*EOF+ end=+^EOF+ contains=NONE
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it's not working for me. I can see that the `after/syntax/sh.vim` has loaded in `:script`, but it's not making any difference.

Comment: I don't understand what `matchgroup` is for and I have not defined it anywhere else, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @paradroid https://asciinema.org/a/ZY1OGWo6Z6eWZjTViipcOcyx0

Comment: @paradroid matchgroup is the name of the highlight group to apply to whatever was matched by `start` and `end` regexes.

Comment: Thanks. I still cannot get it to work at the moment, but this is clearly a separate issue.